# PHP cURL Web Crawler

Tags: php, curl

This code is running fine in terminal when I run the file as

```
$php webcrawler.php
```

However, I am curious on what I need to do to make it run on URLs specified in the console i.e.

```
$php webcrawler.php http://samplesite.com
```

Here is the full code I have so far:

```
class Ga_track
{
  function get_ga_implemented($url)
  {
      $options = array(
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, // return web page
          CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE, // don't return headers
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", // handle all encodings
          CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)",       // who am i
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE, //ssl verify host
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE, //ssl verify peer
          CURLOPT_NOBODY => FALSE
      );

      $ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

      //2> Grab content of the url using CURL
      $content         = curl_exec($ch);
      $flag1_trackpage = false; //FLag for the phrase '_trackPageview'
      $flag2_ga_js     = false; //FLag for the phrase 'ga.js'

      // Script Regex
      $script_regex = "/<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/i";

      // UA_ID Regex
      $ua_regex = "/UA-[0-9]{5,}-[0-9]{1,}/";


      preg_match_all($script_regex, $content, $inside_script);

      for ($i = 0; $i < count($inside_script[0]); $i++)
      {
          if (stristr($inside_script[0][$i], "ga.js"))
              $flag2_ga_js = TRUE;
          if (stristr($inside_script[0][$i], "_trackPageview"))
              $flag1_trackpage = TRUE;
      }


      preg_match_all($ua_regex, $content, $ua_id);

      //6> Check whether all 3 word phrases are present or not.
      if ($flag2_ga_js && $flag1_trackpage && count($ua_id > 0))
          return ($ua_id);
      else
          return (NULL);
  }
  }

  $ga_obj = new Ga_track();

  $url = "http://www.samplesite.com";


  $ua_id = $ga_obj->get_ga_implemented($url);
  if ($ua_id == NULL)
  {
  echo "USING GA: NO\r\n";
  }
  else
  {
  echo "USING GA: YES\r\n";

  }
```

Comment: you check $argv for this http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: Thanks I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to find a solution for using the URL in the command line. I have to use cli and pass in the args. I am still having some trouble with it reading the content, but that is a separate issue. Here is the updated code:

```
class track {


function __construct($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
if(!$this->isCli()) die("Please use php-cli!");
if (!function_exists('curl_init')) die("Please install cURL!");
    $this->hp = $arg1;
    $this->rlevel = $arg2;
    $this->rmax = $arg3;
}


function isCli() {
    return php_sapi_name()==="cli";
}


function getContent() {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->hp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
      return $content;
}



function checkGA($content) {

  $flag_ga      = false;

  $script_regex = "/<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/i";

  preg_match_all($script_regex, $content, $inside_script);

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($inside_script[0]); $i++)
  {
      if (stristr($inside_script[0][$i], "ga.js"))
        $flag_ga = TRUE;
      else
        return (NULL);

  }

}

}

/*
 *
 * Echo Output
 *
 */

$track_obj = new track();

$ga = $track_obj->checkGA($content);

  if ($ga == NULL) {
    echo "USING GA: NO\r\n";
  }
  else {
    echo "USING GA: YES\r\n";
  }
```